# Proper translations on manager titles on business cards

Tags: translation, vocabulary, simplified-characters

So far I have

President • 总统

FOUNDER • 创办人

CEO • 主席

CMO • 营销总监

Are these the correct characters to use on a business card for each title listed above?

Comment: Without context, it is hard to tell what president would be translated to. Banks tend to give out such inflated [corporate titles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_title) freely to make their customers feel important. Traditionally, a president is equivalent to the position of a CEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go over your list one by one. Please note I am talking about the mainland and not sure it is true for HK or Taiwan.

1) President • 总统

It is true only if this president is managing a country, otherwise don't call him/her 总统.
Depends on the type of organization, a president could be:

- 总统 if he/she is the top governor of a country
- 主席 if he/she is the leader of a club
- 董事长 if he/she is the chairman of a board
- 校长 if he/she is the leader of a school

So this one could be tricky and you really need to bring the context in.

2) FOUNDER • 创办人

This translation is fine, or you can say 创始人.

3) CEO • 主席

Most cases this will be translated to 总裁, but it can also be left as is and no translation required... It has been kind of a fashion to print CXO in the business card or title.

4) CMO • 营销总监

This is fine.

Comment: CEO is 行政总裁 to be more accurate.

Comment: I believe CEO translated to `首席执行官` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

President • 总统 (for people like Obama)、 董事长 (chairman of board) 、(副)总裁 (vice) president

FOUNDER • 创始人

CEO • 首席执行官

CMO • 市场总监 or 首席市场官